# Locating the textareaInput side by side(3 columns) at required position using R

Tags: r, shiny

I am running an R code. I have displayed the textareaInput dynamically. But I have an issue in positioning.

The output I got is:
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i74zA.png)

The output I expected is to display the textareaInput below the Current week, next week and next 2 week respectively.

The **R code**:

```
observeEvent(input$view,{
output$inputGroup = renderUI({
  input_list <- lapply(1:(nrow(df())*3), function(i) {
    # for each dynamically generated input, give a different name
    inputName <- paste("input", i, sep = "")
    textInputRow<-function (inputId,value) 
    {
      div(style="display:inline-block",
          textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "40px")
      )
    }

    column(4,
    textInputRow(inputName, ""))

  })
  do.call(tagList, input_list)
})
```

Can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: Please try and make a fully reproducible example. Also, this looks like shiny, so you should probably mention that in the title and the tags.

Comment: Try using `fluidRow` and `column`

Comment: Using **fluidRow** produces the output in one column @SBista

Comment: Ideally you should try using a bootstrap template that can help you with columning with just a div https://github.com/amrrs/rshiny_html_template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further elaborate my comment on using `fluidRow` and `column` I am posting a sample code below:

```
   ui <- fluidPage(
     fluidRow(
       column(3, h3("Total Time Spent:")),
       column(3, numericInput("num1", "Current Week:", value = 1)),
       column(3, numericInput("num2", "Next Week:", value = 1)),
       column(3, numericInput("num3", "Next 2 Week:", value = 1))

     ),
     fluidRow(
       column(3),
       column(9,uiOutput("inputGroup"))
     )

   )



   server <- function(input,output){

     output$inputGroup = renderUI({
       input_list <- lapply(1:9, function(i) {
         # for each dynamically generated input, give a different name
         inputName <- paste("input", i, sep = "")
         textInputRow<-function (inputId,value) 
         {
           div(style="display:inline-block",
               textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "40px")
           )
         }

         column(4,
                textInputRow(inputName, ""))

       })
       do.call(tagList, input_list)
     })

   }


   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This code generates the output as follows:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: **Thanks**. It helped me a lot. :-)

Comment: Could you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you?